# Custom axis with lines to labels

Tags: r, label, line, margin, axis

I am not sure how to phrase this question, but I am trying to add labels with lines to the corresponding point on a basic scatterplot. So far I have the following:

```
example <- data.frame(name=paste("label_",1:200,sep=""),plot=rep(FALSE,200),rank=c(1:200),score=exp(seq(6,0,length.out=200)))
example$plot[c(1:3,7,8,35,37,150:155,183)] <- TRUE

plot(x=example$score,y=example$rank,ylim=rev(range(c(1:nrow(example)))),axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="Score",frame.plot=FALSE)
axis(side=1,labels=TRUE)
axis(side=2,labels=example$name[which(example$plot==TRUE)],at=example$rank[which(example$plot==TRUE)],las=1,tick=FALSE)
points(x=example$score[which(example$plot==TRUE)],y=example$rank[which(example$plot==TRUE)],col="Red",cex=1.5,pch=16)
```

The code gives the following plot:

[image: What I currently have.]

This would work well for my purposes, except the labels overlap really badly. I am looking for a general method to make a graph like the following:

[image: What I would like to have.]

The code lies within a function, so it needs to work for any variation on the general dataset. I am looking into the code behind `safeplot` in the `safe` package, but so far I cannot replicate what they did to solve a similar problem.

I have now also tried using the `linestack()` function in the `vegan` package.

```
par(mar=c(5,10,4,2))
plot(x=example$score,y=example$rank,ylim=rev(range(c(1:nrow(example)))),axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="Score",frame.plot=FALSE)
axis(side=1,labels=TRUE)
points(x=example$score[which(example$plot==TRUE)],y=example$rank[which(example$plot==TRUE)],col="Red",cex=1.5,pch=16)
linestack(x=example$rank[which(example$plot==TRUE)],labels=example$name[which(example$plot==TRUE)],add=TRUE,side="left",air=1.1,at=0,hoff=2)
```

However, `linestack()` just gave me the following:

[image]

I tried varying all the parameters and could not get the labels to separate.

Comment: You can draw those lines and labels with `lines()` and `text()` functions.

Comment: The `lines()` and `text()` functions only draw within the plot region, not in the margins.

Comment: `lines` and `text` can draw in the margin with `par(xpd=TRUE)`.

Comment: I tried that as well. It is not clear to me how the coordinate system works when `xpd=TRUE`.

Comment: It's the same coordinate system as the plotting region. What I like to do when plotting outside the inner region is first get everything I need in the plotting region, then call `par(new=TRUE, xpd=TRUE)` followed by `plot(NA, NA, type='n', xlim=my.xlim, ylim=my.ylim)`, where `my.xlim` and `my.ylim` are convenient xaxis and yaxis ranges for plotting outside the margins, e.g., `my.xlim=c(0,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here, notably that normally you can't draw outside the plotting region as clipping obscures anything outside the limits (i.e. in the margins). You also need to leave a lot of space in that margin to accommodate the labels and the lines.

Whilst this is a bigger job than something I can get into now on SO, I can suggest that you look at the `linestack()` function in the **vegan** package and how it is used in the `vegan:::plot.prc()` method.

I recently used the `linestack() function to do something very similar to what you describe to improve some plots from the **glmnet** package. If you need more help comment back and I'll see about hacking an example together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check out linestack() and let you know if I can get it to work. In my actual code I did increase the margin, I just didn't bother to add the line of code for the example. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the `linestack()` function, and could not quite get it to work. I updated my question with the code I ran.

Comment: When you get time, I would really appreciate an example. This still seems like the most efficient solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the problem. The `linestack()` function uses the `strheight` function as a multiplier when separating the labels. When I assigned the `ylim` to the reverse in my plot call it caused `strheight` to go negative - therefore the labels wouldn't separate. The function works like a charm with a negative `air` value. THANK YOU!

Comment: Nice diagnosis. I noticed the issue whilst trying to provide an example but didn't have time to solve it before I went out. I'll speak with the maintainer of vegan and see if we can change the underlying code to not produce negative strheight values.

Comment: Yea a simple absolute value would fix the trick. Luckily the authors of the package made all of the code for `linestack()` public. I ended up rewriting the function for my purposes, but it works perfectly now.

Comment: @PatrickT I posted the code. Please keep in mind I wrote the code when I was still learning, and I'm sure it could be improved and may have bugs. I did spend any time cleaning it up before posting.

Comment: @dayne, I meant to ask for it, is it in a repo, do you have a url for it? thanks in advance.

Comment: @PatrickT I edited the answer to include the code, but it looks like the edit has not been accepted yet.

Comment: @PatrickT My edit was rejected. All I did was rewrite the `linestack` function from the `vegan` package. You just need to fix the `ht <- air * strheight(names(x), cex = cex)` line by wrapping an `abs` around the `strheight` call.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `spread.labs` function in the TeachingDemos package and the `spread.labels` function in the plotrix package for ways of choosing where to position the labels.

Setting `par(xpd=NA)` will let you use `text`,`lines`,`segments` and other functions to draw outside of the plotting area.

Also the function `grconvertX` may be helpful in finding the horizontal position for labels and line segments.